# Converting a table to matrix of 0's and 1's

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table of Hosts and event Id's Like

```
Hosts     |   Event_id
system1          1
System2          1
System1          2
System3          1
System2          2
```

etc.

Now I want to convert them into a matrix like

```
             |  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 ....
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    System1  |  1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0 ....
    System2  |  1    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    0 ....
    System3  |  1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0 ....
```

How to do it in SQL?

Comment: Thanks for finding that in R, I would want to know how to do in SQL.

Comment: Off topic: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) has run out of disk space on the C drive...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I have MySQL and Oracle with me

Comment: I got the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074319/dynamically-pivoting-a-table-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use pivot to get this done, but this cannot be dynamic, you have to know the columns in your matrix before hand.

The below query works for event_id between 1 and 9, and if it is greater add it to the select and pivot clauses accordingly.

```
declare @t table 
(
 hosts VARCHAR(20), event_id int
)
insert into @t values ('system1','1')
insert into @t values ('System2','1')
insert into @t values ('System1','2')
insert into @t values ('System3','1')
insert into @t values ('System2','2')
insert into @t values ('System3','4')
select * from @t

Select Hosts,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
from 
(
select hosts,hosts as Hosts1,Event_id from @t 
) P
pivot 
(
count(Hosts1) for Event_id in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
) as pvt
```

you can learn more about pivot from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Implementation of dynamic pivot for the above sql

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
 hosts VARCHAR(20), event_id int
)
insert into #t values ('system1','1')
insert into #t values ('System2','1')
insert into #t values ('System1','2')
insert into #t values ('System3','1')
insert into #t values ('System2','2')
insert into #t values ('System3','4')
select * from #t

declare @sql varchar(4000)
declare @ColumnList VARCHAR(2000)

select @columnList = stuff((select ',[' + CAST(event_id AS VARCHAR) + ']' from (select distinct event_id from #t) a1  for xml path('')),1,1,'') -- get the concatenated list of the event_id columns seperated by a comma.
select @columnList

SET @sql = 
'Select Hosts,' + @columnList + '
from 
(
select hosts,hosts as Hosts1,Event_id from #t 
) P
pivot 
(
count(Hosts1) for Event_id in (' + @columnList + ')
) as pvt'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks Surendra, But I am not sure of the Event_id's.

Comment: then you have to go with the dynamic pivot, before going to that, please check the above query in your system and let me know it works, then we can go for dynamic pivot solution.

Comment: I don't have a sql server, so tried in Mysql it works for me. I have the data in CSV format

Comment: I dont have the mysql knowledge, the above the solution is edited to run in sql server, check if you can get it done in mysql basing on this.

Answer (score 0):

While it *is* possible to construct pivots dynamically,  typically it's far easier and more flexible to handle the display logic st the application level (e.g. with a simple PHP loop)

Comment: Could you share how to do it?