# Dynamic pivot table - sql developer

Tags: oracle, pivot

I tried to create my own procedure for dynamic pivot but it isn't working. 
My procedure is created correctly but when I want to execute it - it isn't working. 
Firstly I had tried bluefeet's procedure and it was working. link to this question
 [Dynamically pivoting a table Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074319/dynamically-pivoting-a-table-oracle?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My procedure should count occurrence of values from column p_key.

Maybe somebody has any idea why my procedure is not working.

code for my table

```
create table aa_tabela (
C_ID number(3,0),
gcm number(1,0), 
p_key varchar2(30), 
p_count  number(6,0));
```

I insert few values

```
INSERT ALL 
 INTO aa_tabela (C_ID, gcm, p_key, p_count )
     VALUES (1, 7, 'Data Mining', 2)
 INTO aa_tabela (C_ID, gcm, p_key, p_count )
     VALUES (2, 5, 'Data Mining', 3)
 INTO aa_tabela (C_ID, gcm, p_key, p_count )
     VALUES (3, 3, 'Reporting', 1)
 INTO aa_tabela (C_ID, gcm, p_key, p_count )
     VALUES (4, 3, 'Olap', 5)
 INTO aa_tabela (C_ID, gcm, p_key, p_count )
     VALUES (5, 1, 'Reporting', 4)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

My static PIVOT table is working:

```
  SELECT GCM,
   SUM(case when p_key = 'Data Mining' then p_count end) AS Data_Mining,
   SUM(case when p_key = 'Reporting' then p_count end) AS Reporting,
   SUM(case when p_key = 'Olap' then p_count end) AS OLAP 
from aa_tabela
group by  gcm
order by gcm desc;
```

Result:

```
   |GCM | DATA_MINING | REPORTING    |   OLAP   |

   | 7  |      2      |              |          |
   | 5  |      3      |              |          |
   | 3  |             |      1       |    5     |
   | 1  |             |      4       |          |
```

My procedure for dynamic pivot creates correctly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure test_abc(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
AS
   sql_query long := 'select gcm ';

BEGIN
    for x in (select distinct p_key from aa_tabela order by 1)
    loop
        sql_query := sql_query ||
          ' , sum(case when p_key = '''||x.p_key||''' then p_count end) as '||x.p_key;

          dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
    end loop;

    sql_query := sql_query || ' from aa_tabela group by gcm';

    open p_cursor for sql_query;
END;
```

/
PROCEDURE TEST_ABC compiled

I execute my procedure by following code:

```
variable x refcursor
exec test_abc(:x);
print x
```

Error Message:

```
Error starting at line : 215 in command -
exec test_abc(:x)
Error report -
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at "MAGDA.TEST_ABC", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
```

Comment: Check what is in sql_query variable using `dbms_output.put_line` for example - you will then see any bug in your SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error because one of values is "Data Mining". In your procedure it's translated to column alias like `as Data Mining`.
You need to change space to underscore or add quotaion marks in line 9:

```
      ' , sum(case when p_key = '''||x.p_key||''' then p_count end) as "'||x.p_key||'"';
```