# Oracle SQL Summary report

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm a new junior developer using reporting as a tool to learn the database structure, we have a reporting tool called Cyberquery to produce these reports but i like to mirror what i do in that in SQL Developer so i can learn both.
Unfortunately i have hit a wall with this problem...

I am trying to produce a summary report of product sales over 24 months, broken down by each month like the table below.

```
                      |   2014/10   |   2014/11   |   2014/12   |   Total    
item no | description | qty | value | qty | value | qty | value | qty | value 
   a      item a         4     20      1      5      2      10     7      35
   b      item b         1     10      2      20     3      30     6      60
```

Unfortunately i have not been able to format the query to display the results like this. The sql i have been using goes like this:

```
select * from(
select i.item_no, i.description, sl.line_value, sl.line_qty, sh.invoice_date
from sales_line sl
join sales_header sh on sh.invoice_no = sl.invoice_no
join item i on i.item_no = sl.item_no
where sh.invoice_date >=  add_months((last_day(sysdate)+1),-24)
)
```

So i have tried a few different ways, originally i thought it would be a case of just using group by but after i couldn't get that to work i had a look at using the pivot function and couldn't get that to work either.

Is this possible in SQL?

Kind Regards,
Richard

Comment: Yes.  It's possible, you'd have to use a DYNAMIC pivot or hardcode current-date - 1... 2...3.... to 24. and use case statements to evaluate against the invoice date.  A dynamic Pivot is needed as the column headers would fluctuate based on date run.  meaning the names of the columns would be dynamic; thus dynamic SQL.  When using a case statement all you could do is list periods  w/o the year/mo.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074319/dynamically-pivoting-a-table-oracle

Comment: @xQbert , Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hope you get there.  If not come back &Update question with more details, I'm sure we can provide more detailed/better guidance.