# PL/SQL Oracle - convert rows into fields dynamically

Tags: sql, plsql

I already checked same scenario like this but unfortunately still don't get it :( , I tried some code but still failed to work

- convert rows into fields dynamically (fields are depends on number of rows and no. of rows are depends on TYPE)

Table

```
TYPE                |ATTR_NAME              | ATTR_VALUE
**sample flat rate  |Activity               | N
**sample flat rate  |code                   | PLAN_999
**sample flat rate  |codes object           | object
**sample low  rate  |Activity               | Y
**sample low  rate  |code                   | PLAN_1299
**sample low  rate  |codes object           | charge
**sample low  rate  |indicator              | 0
```

Codes:

```
declare
  sqlqry VARCHAR2(4001);
  cols VARCHAR2(4001);
begin
  select listagg('''' || ATTR_NAME || ''' as "' || ATTR_NAME || '"', ',') within group (order by ATTR_NAME)
  into   cols
  from   (select distinct ATTR_NAME from temp_2);
sqlqry :=
'select * from
(
    select *
    from temp_2
)
pivot
(
  MIN(ATTR_VALUE) for ATTR_NAME in (' || cols  || ')    
)'
;
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074319/dynamically-pivoting-a-table-oracle) can be useful

Comment: @Aleksej .. Thanks .. I successfully executed the PL/SQL but I got an error in executing the result 

    variable x ref cursor
    exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
    print x;

Comment: please post what you tried and the error you've got; this will help people to better understand the issue and give you a good answer

Comment: sorry :)

Bind Variable "X" is NOT DECLARED

Comment: but doing what?... there is no X in what you posted :)

Comment: there's an x on the pl/sql script

    max(case when r_key = '''||x.r_key||''' then r_value end) as '||x.r_key;

Comment: for x in (select distinct r_key from s_projectroles order by 1)
       loop
          sql_query := sql_query ||
            ' , max(case when r_key = '''||x.r_key||''' then r_value end) as '||x.r_key;
       
              dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

Comment: Are you talking about the other question mentioned in the comments above? That has a bind variable `:x` defined as a refcursor, and a PL/SQL record `x`. But I think we need to focus on your own question and code, which has no `x` anywhere.

Comment: Yes @WilliamRobertson , I want some answer also and the same time I want to view the result based of the script provided on the link.

Answer (score 0):

With a table ilke the following:

```
create table temp_2 (TYPE, ATTR_NAME, ATTR_VALUE) as (
    select 'sample flat rate',  'Activity'    , 'N' from dual union all
    select 'sample flat rate',  'code'        , 'PLAN_999' from dual union all
    select 'sample flat rate',  'codes object', 'object' from dual union all
    select 'sample low  rate',  'Activity'    , 'Y' from dual union all
    select 'sample low  rate',  'code'        , 'PLAN_1299' from dual union all
    select 'sample low  rate',  'codes object', 'charge' from dual union all
    select 'sample low  rate',  'indicator'   , '0' from dual
)
```

this is a working example:

```
SQL> variable x refcursor
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    sqlqry VARCHAR2(4001);
  3    cols VARCHAR2(4001);
  4  begin
  5    select listagg('''' || ATTR_NAME || ''' as "' || ATTR_NAME || '"', ',') within group (order by ATTR_NAME)
  6    into   cols
  7    from   (select distinct ATTR_NAME from temp_2);
  8  sqlqry :=
  9      'select * from
 10      (
 11          select *
 12          from temp_2
 13      )
 14      pivot
 15      (
 16        MIN(ATTR_VALUE) for ATTR_NAME in (' || cols  || ')
 17      )';
 18  open :x for sqlqry;
 19  end;
 20  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :x

TYPE             Activity  code      codes obj indicator
---------------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
sample low  rate Y         PLAN_1299 charge    0
sample flat rate N         PLAN_999  object

SQL>
```

Comment: @Aleksej..sorry for the confusions .. we only have one table.. Temp_2.. I already updated the above codes..

Comment: It's properly working but it only displayed 3 fields when I run it in my real table ... may real table has 15 rows .. so meaning 15 'fields' should be displayed..and if I change different TYPE depending how many rows in it should also be equal to number of fields to be displayed

Comment: And if I filtered it by type    
    select distinct ATTR_NAME from temp_2 where type = 'sample low  rate'  .. the result is not filtered